# Avoid Google country specific redirect when searching in the url bar in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, google-search

I want to avoid Chrome redirecting me to a country specific landing page for Google whenever I search for something through the url bar. Is there a setting for this? I can only seem to find a setting for home button / default page.
Can be quite annoying when using VPN and you need more English relevant search results.

Answer (score 0):

See [this comment (and answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790658/url-www-google-com-google-is-getting-redirected-to-different-url-www-google-co#comment49714556_30790658)

Also there is a way for a permanent solution (Firefox on the other hand needs [a plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/always-com-googlecom-in-englis/)), see for example here: http://dottech.org/158839/prevent-google-from-redirecting-you-to-its-local-homepage-tip/

(note, that site claims the trick works on Firefox too, so it might be outdated, google for other solutions)