# URL www.google.com / google is getting redirected to different URL www.google.co.in

Tags: google-chrome, url, browser, redirect

I'm trying to open www.google.com (USA) but somehow it's opening www.google.in

Any ideas why it would do that? This is happening in all browsers I have on my machine (Win7) and my date time/location settings are correctly set (US Mountain time). What settings in the browser/system would impact this behaviour. One of my co-worker is also seeing the same issue. Now, If I got to a remote windows machine (there www.google.com renders the correct US www.google.com site).

[image]

as soon as I press Control+K or enter after entering www.google.com in address bar, it changes and redirects it to www.google.co.in/.../x./.xxx./

[image]

Comment: 1500 rep and ask a question about why your browser doesn't work? has your account been hijacked?

Comment: no. im just curious.

Comment: www.google.com/ncr -- will fix if this is happening. Sorry didnt do much research first.

Comment: This a valid question about a real (and super-annoying) problem. It has also been already [asked many times](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=google.com+redirects+to+country+site) so maybe a duplicate/cleanup is in order? (example: you go to Thailand for vacation, try to google something and you get a page full of gibberish - they are actually thai letters, but to 99% of world they mean nothing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: **www.google.com/ncr** and press enter/control+K

and after this, even if you try www.google.com / google and press control+K, it'll work and won't redirect to www.google.co.in